# CSS How to style a specific <li>?

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

Using jQuery, I wanted to know how I can style a specific list item?

For example, I'd like to style the first `<li>` (first-child) to give it its own style, then give the next five list items heir own styles, and then the next five their own styles, etc.

I read something a long time ago about `:nth` but didn't quite understand it. Is this easy to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

`nth-child` allows you to provide an expression which is evaluated to give a set of elements. The simplest expression you can provide is just a number (e.g. `nth-child(3)`) which will apply the style to the 3rd child.

You can use it to apply styles to every 3rd child by using an expression such as `3n`, and can even use `odd` or `even` to apply styles to (obviously) every odd or even child.

However, I don't think you can use it apply styles to repeated blocks of multiple elements (e.g. style 5 elements one way, and the next 5 another) with a single expression.

Answer (score 1):

Google helps a lot: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

```
ul li:nth-child(5) {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Or jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$("ul li:nth-child(5)").css("color", "#ccc");
```

To style groups of LI:

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
  $("ul li").each(function (index) {
    // This will get the remainder of the division of the li index by 10
    var groupNum = index % 10;

    // Style groups of 5 LIs differently
    if (groupNum<5) {
      $(this).css("color", "#ccc");
    } else {
      $(this).css("color", "#222");
    } 
  });
});
```

Not tested, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: While tempting to simply refer people to Google, one main intent of StackOverflow is to be **the result** of a Google search.

Comment: A "Google first, ask second" approach is in my opinion the correct approach when asking a question on SO. The question can then be more specific and get more precise answers. In this case, I must say that the question phrased as "I read something a long time ago about :nth but didn't quite understand it. Is this easy to achieve?" leads me to think the original poster has not done any (recent) research on the subject and could have come up with a better question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment Marvin I appreciate it. The reason I love stackoverflow, as lazy as it may make me look, is it's much quicker to get more 'on-target' advice and assistance than from trying to skim or read walls of text from web articles. The answers here, including yours were 100 times more helpful, sharper and clearer to me than any article I read about :nth. And since I failed math, that doesn't help either haha. Cheers.